# Function $u$ solves the heat equation $\Longrightarrow$ $\langle x, \nabla u \rangle + 2t u_t$ solves the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am baffling with this homework problem:
Assume that a smooth function u solves the heat equation $u_t − \Delta u = 0.$ Show that also the function
$v(x, t) = \langle x, ∇u(x, t) \rangle + 2tu_t (x, t)$
solves the heat equation. Here $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the innerproduct $ f,g \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} f(x) \cdot g(x) dx$ .

I was considering to use integration by parts but, to my understanding, nothing guarantees that the solution $u$ even vanishes on the boundaries. Some clues are welcome.

Comment: What boundary are you referring to?

Comment: When $|x| \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: So even without integration by part you have no idea why $\langle x, \nabla u\rangle$ is integrable. Your function $v$ might not be well defined.

Comment: True. So I should maybe assume that condition for $u$. Not still sure how to continue.

Comment: If this is a homework, you can definitely ask for clarification.

Comment: Are you sure the brackets are denoting the $L^2$ scalar product and not the euclidean standard scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: In fact I am not sure.

Comment: The brackets here stand for the Euclidean inner product, so $v(x,t) = x_1 u_{x_1} + x_2u_{x_2} + \cdots + x_nu_{x_n} + 2tu_t$. Why are you considering integration by parts? Just plug $v$ into the heat equation and check that you get zero. [Additionally, if I recall correctly this is part (b) of an exercise from Evans, and there is a simpler proof that uses part (a)...]

Comment: I got confused by the notation. In DiBenedettos book that is the standard notation for innerproduct in $L^2$. But I got it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $ denoting the Euclidian scalar product you get
$$v_t = \nabla u \cdot \boldsymbol{x}_t + \boldsymbol{x} \cdot \partial_t \nabla u + 2 (u_{tt} + u_t) = \boldsymbol{x} \cdot \partial_t \nabla u + 2 (tu_{tt} + u_t) \tag{1}$$
Use [Green's Vector identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green%27s_vector_identity) for the $\Delta \langle \boldsymbol{x}, \nabla u \rangle$ and the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_of_gradient_is_zero) that $\nabla \times \nabla v \equiv 0 \: \forall \: v \in \mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{align}\Delta v &= \nabla u \cdot \Delta   \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{x}  \cdot \Delta \nabla u + 2 \nabla \cdot \Big( (\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \nabla) \nabla u + \boldsymbol{x} \times (\nabla \times \nabla u) \Big) + 2 t \Delta u_t \\
&= - \boldsymbol{x}  \cdot \Delta \nabla u + 2 \nabla \cdot \Big( (\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \nabla) \nabla u \Big) + 2 t \Delta u_t \tag{2} \end{align}

The terms including $t$ cancel each other for a smooth $u$ (can interchange differentiations arbitrarily). Formally, you can define the operator $2 t \partial_t$ which is then applied to $u_t - \Delta u_t$.

To simplify the remaining terms, index notation is employed.
\begin{align} - \boldsymbol{x}  \cdot \Delta \nabla u + 2 \nabla \cdot \Big( (\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \nabla) \nabla u \Big) =& -x_i \partial_i \partial_j\partial_j u + 2 \partial_i (x_j \partial_j\partial_i u ) \\
&= -x_i \partial_i \partial_j\partial_j u + 2 \big( \delta_{ij} \partial_j \partial_i u +  x_i \partial_i\partial_j\partial_j u \big) \\
& = 2  \partial_i \partial_i u +  x_i \partial_i\partial_j\partial_j u  \\
&= 2 \Delta u + \boldsymbol{x} \cdot \nabla \Delta u \end{align}

Clearly, $2u_t - 2 \Delta u = 0$. By interchanging the temporal and spatial derivatives and defining the operator $\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \nabla $ also the last remaining terms cancel.